# Deterministic Time Hierachy Proof by Arora and Barak: Question about time to simulate Turing Machine $M$ that decides separating language

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity

In the book "Computational Complexity: A modern approach", Arora and Barak proof the statement that $DTIME(n) \subsetneq DTIME(n^{1.5})$ by constructing a separating language $L \in DTIME(n^{1.5})$ but $L \notin DTIME(n)$. The language $L$ is the one decided by the following Turing Machine $D$:

> On input $x$, run for $|x|^{1.4}$ steps the Universal Tm $U$ of Theorem 1.9 to simulate the execution of $M_x$ on $x$. If $U$ outputs some bit $b \in \{0,1\}$ in this time, then output the opposite answer (i.e. output $1-b$). Else output $0$.

They now assume towards a contradiction that there would be a TM $M$ that for any $x \in \{0,1\}^*$ halts within $c|x|$ steps and outputs $D(x)$.

They write:

> The time to simulate $M$ by the universal Turing machine $U$ on every input $x$ is at most $c' c |x| \log(|x|)$ for some number $c'$ that depends on the alphabet size and number of tapes and states of $M$ but is independent of |x|.

But Theorem 1.9 about the Universal Turing Machine states:

> There exists a TM $U$ such that for every $x, \alpha \in \{0,1\}^*, U(x,\alpha) = M_{\alpha}(x)$ [...]. **If $M_{\alpha}$ halts on input $x$ within $T$ steps, then $U(x,\alpha)$ halts within $C T \log(T)$ steps**, where $C$ is a number independent of $|x|$ and depending only on $M_{\alpha}'s$ alphabet size, number of tapes, and number of states.

Given this theorem, wouldn't that mean that the time to simulate $M$ by the universal Turing machine $U$ is at most $c' \cdot c |x| \log(c \cdot |x|)$? If not, or it does not matter, why is that?

Comment: The difference is very slight. You can convert one bound to the other by modifying $c’$.

Comment: Thanks! But why would you need the $c$ then anyway? Couldn't one also integrate that into the $c'$ constant? Is there any reason for this distinction?

Comment: The constant $c$ comes from the running time of the original machine, whereas $c’$ comes from the simulation.